# Power BI - keep only total values in a table

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax, reporting, powerbi-desktop

I am working on a Power BI report and I have this matrix:
[image]

In which I have Amount and Rate as values. What I need is to hide all the Rate values for each RATING and keep only the calculated Total Rate in this table.

I tried to Exclude the Rate column, but it just excludes the whole column instead(if I exclude the rate for the column "A-1" it excludes entire "A-1" column).

Is there any way I can achieve what I need?

Thank you in advance! :D

Comment: could you please share your model view and your attempted DAX code?

Comment: Could you provide a snapshot of what happens when you remove the 'Rate' column? I'm not sure what you are explaining.
It would also help if you provide another picture of what you want the visual to look like, even if you have to make a subset of it in excel or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Idea would be to keep the calculations in underlying dataset/ table/ dataframe
Only fetch already calculated Amount in PBI.
Rates would not appear in your report, as you only pull up the calculated & desired column in PBI.
Also BI would be light weight.